# Is it possible to deploy multiple war file in tomcat using Jenkins?

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, tomcat7, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow

I'm Using Jenkins and Tomcat7. if i deploy a single war file in tomcat using Jenkins it's working fine. I tried to deploy multiple different war file in tomcat one by one. first war file was deployed successfully, after that i can't deploy another war file in same tomcat folder.
But i want deploy multiple .war file of different application in single tomcat folder using Jenkins.

Is it possible to deploy multiple war file in tomcat using Jenkins? If it is yes means how can i achieve? OR any other way to solve this issue?

ERROR:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: FAIL - Deployed application at context path /warttwo but context failed to start
```

Comment: How are you deploying the war files right now? And what happens during the second deploy? Do you have any error messages?

Comment: 1.I gave destination machine tomcat username,password and URL in jenkins  2.yes i got some error message.

Comment: Jenkins' plugin for deployment tries to access the application right after it's deployed, to make sure the deployment worked. Is your application accessible right after deploy? If you manually deploy each WAR and access each context right after deploy, would all of them work?

Comment: i couldn't access my apps after getting an error.

Comment: Any help with this??\

Answer (score 2):

In my case:

1. Copy all war files to one folder (**Execute shell** under **Post Steps**)

   > mkdir -p wars
   >   rm -f wars/*
   >   mv app1/target/app1.war wars/
   >   mv app2/target/app2.war wars/
2. Under **Deploy war/ear to a container** under **Post-build Actions** section

   > WAR/EAR files: wars/*.war
   >   Context path: [leave empty]
   >   Containers -> Tomcat URL: http://localhost:8080

Then, you can visit http://localhost:8080/app1 or http://localhost:8080/app2

NOTE: The **Credentials** of **Deploy war/ear to a container** must have **manager-script** role so that can deploy your war files to your **webapps** folder in tomcat